# How to set INPUT:TEXT with value mask

Tags: imacros

I want to set the value (phone number) of text element with input mask:

```
<form method="post" action="form" id="form1"> 
  <input id="xxx" name="yyy" size="20" value="+(___) __________" type="text">
  ...
</form>
```

The usual TAG command doesn't work:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:xxx CONTENT=0123456789012
```

I also tried to paste value from clipboard, with the same result:

```
SET !CLIPBOARD "0123456789012"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:xxx CONTENT={{!CLIPBOARD}}
```

Macro runs without any errors, it successfully selects field, but can't change its value.
Could you please advise me how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use 'iMacros' for Firefox, you may try:

```
SET value "+(123) 4567890123"
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#ctl00_cp1_txtPhone" CHARS={{value}}
```

---

Also a variant for any browser via pseudo-URL:

```
SET value "+(123) 4567890123"
SET S "window.document.getElementById('ctl00_cp1_txtPhone').value = '{{value}}'; undefined;"
URL GOTO=javascript:{{S}}
```

---

Probably, you need something like this:

```
SET value 1234567890
SET value EVAL("'+(' + '{{value}}'.substr(0, 3) + ') ' + '{{value}}'.substr(3, 7);")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:xxx CONTENT={{value}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I can manually copy value to clipboard and paste it in field, it works for any of values as 0123456789012, +(012)3456789012.   
But I can't insert such values into field in script:   
`SET value "1234567890123"  
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:ctl00_cp1_txtPhone CONTENT={{value}}  `
  
`SET value "+(123)4567890123" TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT  FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:ctl00_cp1_txtPhone CONTENT={{value}}  `

Comment: See the updated answer. I hope something of that must help you.

Comment: The variant of realization with embedded javascript solved my problem. Thank you!